# Raspberry Pi 3 and UPS Pico HV3.0A, cold boot

Tags: alternative-power

I am already building a Pi 3 mobile project, with a 5 inch screen, Bluetooth keyboard and so on. What Ii am interested in is using the new version of UPS Pico HV3.0A, that supports up to 3A of current, to power my project.

The question is this: Does any one know whether this UPS supports cold boot? I mean the ups is supposed to provide power when there is no external USB power, given that already the Pi  has booted and generating a pulse train, (produced by the software daemons). So if the Pi is shutdown, there is no external USB power.

Is there anyway for the UPS to start providing power and boot the Pi?
I searched a lot in the UPS manual and the UPS Pico forums but nothing came up.
So if someone has any ideas, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like it should be able to power up a pi in cold boot. Though it might not have the power to boot a pi4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on the topic but I believe that the Pi will still place a load on your ups after it is shut down. Furthermore although you can't boot up your Pi using your pico ups what you could do is place a button between the ups and the Pi to allow you to temporarily cut power to the Pi, which would boot the Pi. Anther possible solution to your problem and this is the solution that I would recommend is that you google tutorials on reducing your pi's power usage so that you can have it run for longer on battery instead of having to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Mohammad Ali, what i want to achieve here is when there is no external usb power,  to power and boot the raspberry pi.  As i understand from the ups pico manual, in order to provide power, it needs first to know that the rpi is active and working. So  the switch you proposed wouldn't work if the ups pico  doesn't provide any power.  Think of it as a laptop. A laptop can boot whether there is external power or not.